# accessing values in one form on submitting another form in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two sections here, one is category section, other is log in section. I want that the selected category can be accessed in the login.php by simpe `$cat = $_POST['logincategory']; echo $cat;` but the selected radio value is in-accessible and on submitting the form an error shows up saying :
`Notice: Undefined index: logincategory`

```
<section  id="categorysection" action="login.php"  form="loginform">


        <ul style="font-size:20px; font-color:#000;">
            <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="administrator"> Administrator </li>
            <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="director"> Director (IQAC) </li>
            <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="vicechancellor"> Vice Chancellor </li>
            <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="registrar"> Registrar </li>
            <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="facutly"> Faculty/Dept. Representative </li>
        </ul>
    <button id="logincategorybutton" type="submit" class="login-button" value="&rarr; Login" hidden>Login</button>

</section>
<section id="loginsection" >
  <form method="post" action="login.php" class="login" id="loginform">
    <p>
       <label for="username" style="color:#000; font-weight:700">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:300px" required placeholder="enter username" maxlength="20">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="password" style="color:#000; font-weight:700">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:300px" required placeholder="enter password" maxlength="20">
    </p>

    <p class="login-submit">
      <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
      <button type="submit" class="login-button" onclick="document.getElementById('logincategorybutton').click();" value="&rarr; Login">Login</button>
    </p>

   <!-- <p class="forgot-password"><a href="index.html">Forgot your password?</a></p>-->
  </form>

  <sup style="color:#000; padding-left:150px;"> ** both username and password must be alpha-numeric between 4-20 characters</sup>
</section>



</body>
```

EDIT: brought the radio buttons in form tag, still facing the same problem

```
<section  id="categorysection" >


        <form form="loginform">
        <ul style="font-size:20px; font-color:#000;">
            <li> <input type="radio"  name="logincategory" value="administrator"> Administrator </li>
            <li> <input type="radio"  name="logincategory" value="director"> Director (IQAC) </li>
            <li> <input type="radio"  name="logincategory" value="vicechancellor"> Vice Chancellor </li>
            <li> <input type="radio"  name="logincategory" value="registrar"> Registrar </li>
            <li> <input type="radio"  name="logincategory" value="facutly"> Faculty/Dept. Representative </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
    <button id="logincategorybutton" type="submit" class="login-button" value="&rarr; Login" hidden>Login</button>

</section>
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown `form method="post` is in the question. The issue is your form element `logincategory` is not in the `<form>` tag

Comment: but i added form="loginform" in former section..doesn't that make it a part of the form already ?

Comment: No it wont post, only input elements within the form will be posted. Move your current `<form>` tag above the top `<section>`

Comment: @AkashGupta look AlexP answer, is the most correct, plus, go study some HTML, you need that.

Comment: yep..mistake accepted, but i solved it the other way round. using the form attribute being added to the radio buttons individually rather than in the section tag.
I accept using action in section tag is a catastrophic mistake..but i was just experimenting to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the revised code.

All the input elements need to be wrapped in the form. Notice I have also removed the second submit button as you only need one per form.

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" class="login" id="loginform">
  <section>
    <ul style="font-size:20px; font-color:#000;">
        <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="administrator"> Administrator </li>
        <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="director"> Director (IQAC) </li>
        <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="vicechancellor"> Vice Chancellor </li>
        <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="registrar"> Registrar </li>
        <li> <input type="radio" name="logincategory" value="facutly"> Faculty/Dept. Representative </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section id="loginsection" >
      <p>
        <label for="username" style="color:#000; font-weight:700">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:300px" required placeholder="enter username" maxlength="20">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="password" style="color:#000; font-weight:700">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:300px" required placeholder="enter password" maxlength="20">
      </p>
      <p class="login-submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="login-button" onclick="document.getElementById('logincategorybutton').click();" value="&rarr; Login">Login</button>
      </p>
     <!-- <p class="forgot-password"><a href="index.html">Forgot your password?</a></p>-->
    <sup style="color:#000; padding-left:150px;"> ** both username and password must be alpha-numeric between 4-20 characters</sup>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: **Chinese proverb**: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: Thanx for the help Alex, but that quite obvious to put everything in a single form. Due to some CSS reason I cannot put them in a single form.

Comment: @Fred Point taken, however its easier to display in code than explain.

Comment: well i just solved the problem, i was actually putting the form attribute in the section tag to make it part of the actual form, instead i had to make each radio button part of the form individually by adding a form attribute to each of them :)

Comment: don't you think putting all the things in the same form makes it a little more difficult to place them properly on the page. We should make use of this new form attribute added in HTML5 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<section id="loginsection" >
  <form method="post" action="login.php" class="login" id="loginform">
    <p>
       <label for="username" style="color:#000; font-weight:700">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:300px" required placeholder="enter username" maxlength="20">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="password" style="color:#000; font-weight:700">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:300px" required placeholder="enter password" maxlength="20">
    </p>

    <p class="login-submit">
      <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
      <button type="submit" class="login-button"  value="&rarr; Login">Login</button>
    </p>

   <!-- <p class="forgot-password"><a href="index.html">Forgot your password?</a></p>-->
  </form>

      </section>






<section  id="categorysection" >    

        <form form="loginform">
            <ul style="font-size:20px; font-color:#000;">
                <li> <input type="radio" form="loginform" name="logincategory" value="administrator"> Administrator </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" form="loginform" name="logincategory" value="director"> Director (IQAC) </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" form="loginform" name="logincategory" value="vicechancellor"> Vice Chancellor </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" form="loginform" name="logincategory" value="registrar"> Registrar </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" form="loginform" name="logincategory" value="facutly"> Faculty/Dept. Representative </li>
            </ul>
        </form>     
</section>
```

Comment: guys care to see, that the latter section is not placed under the form tag directly, but has been made a part of the form instead, so now I can actually place this section almost anywhere in the page (that was needed in my case actually)

Comment: @Fred This is a new HTML5 attribute and it is valid, the radio options will submit - Only for people with a browser that supports it!

Comment: @AlexP Ok thanks. Personally I like what HTML5 has to offer and for so many aspects, however I don't mess with it, when it comes to forms. It's best I leave well enough alone *as it were*, up until everyone has an HTML5 compatible Web browser, which may happen in what... 5, 10 years? It's a good option, hey don't get me wrong, I'm all for evolution, but the "Old School" methods (not all, but many) will always have its place, even and mostly with forms. Much appreciated on the insight, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your radio buttons **within** the form tag. Also, you cannot use a `section` tag to submit a form.